# How do I place a repeating notification 8 clock set daily?

Tags: android, notifications

I need to get 8 clock repeating notification every day. I have fixed some coding for it and I see an error. Below are some picks. How do I set an 8 clock alarm

AlarmActivity

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private int REQUEST_CODE = 45645;
private String id = "myname";
private long timeInMilliSeconds = 30;
static String APP_TAG = "classname";
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    initAlarm();
}

private void initAlarm() {

    //creating intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(id);
    boolean alarmRunning = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
    ) != null;

    //setting broadcast
    broadcastReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(id)
    );

    //setting alarm
    long ensurePositiveTime = Math.max(timeInMilliSeconds, 0L);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    //Check if alarm is already running
    if (!alarmRunning) {
        alarmManager.set(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ensurePositiveTime,
                pendingIntent
        );

    } else {
        updateAlarm();
        Log.e("Alarm", "Alarm already running.!");
    }
}

private void updateAlarm() {

    //calculating alarm time and creating pending intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(id);
    long ensurePositiveTime = Math.max(timeInMilliSeconds, 0L);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    //removing previously running alarm
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

    //setting broadcast
    broadcastReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(id)
    );

    //Check if alarm is already running
    alarmManager.set(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ensurePositiveTime,
            pendingIntent
    );

    Log.e("Alarm", "Alarm updated..!");

}

/**
 * Use this to cancel alarm
 */
private void cancelAlarm() {


    if (pendingIntent != null) {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
    if (broadcastReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        broadcastReceiver = null;
    }

    Log.e("Alarm", "Alarm has been canceled..!");
}
```

}

MyReceiver

```
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WakeLocker.acquire(context);
        createNotification(context);
        WakeLocker.release();
    }

    /***
     * It creates notification
     * @param context
     */
    private void createNotification(Context context) {
        String channelId = "fcm_default_channel";
        String channelName = "notification";

        Uri defaultSoundUri =
                RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("I am alarm from my activity")
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel(
                            channelId,
                            channelName,
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                    );
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

WakeLocker

```
public abstract class WakeLocker {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public static void acquire(Context c) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) c.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, AlarmActivity.APP_TAG);
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null){
            wakeLock.release();
        }
        wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

How do I set the 8 clock alarm model? If you know, I ask for your help. In this coding, I get an alarm only once.

Answer (score 0):

**Just change the code of init alarm and update alarm**

This will trigger alarm everyday at 8 AM

#### in initAlarm()

```
private void initAlarm() {

    //creating intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(id);
    boolean alarmRunning = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
    ) != null;

    //setting broadcast
    broadcastReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(id)
    );

    //setting alarm
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    //Check if alarm is already running
    if (!alarmRunning) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        long startUpTime  = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                startUpTime,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent
        );
    } else {
        updateAlarm();
        Log.e("Alarm", "Alarm already running.!");
    }
}
```

#### in updateAlarm()

```
private void updateAlarm() {

    //calculating alarm time and creating pending intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(id);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    //removing previously running alarm
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

    //setting broadcast
    broadcastReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(id)
    );

    //Check if alarm is already running
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    long startUpTime  = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            startUpTime,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent
    );

    Log.e("Alarm", "Alarm updated..!");

}
```